# Loading nib using loadNibNamed:owner:options: designate initializer

Tags: objective-c, uiview, nib, loadnibnamed

I have a nib file with its class (`UIView`) assigned to it in the inspector, So when I need to show that view I loaded it using the method :
`loadNibNamed:owner:options:`

So if I have to do some initialization when I load the nib, what is the way to know that in the nib's `UIView` class like the `initWithNibName:bundle` For the `UIViewController`?

I appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a combination of `initWithCoder:` and `awakeFromNib` which are each called at different times during the instantiation (the former) and configuration (the latter).